# Problem with SMTP emails sent via PhpMailer: Helo Not Accepted

Tags: php, smtp, phpmailer

The error it's giving me is:

SMTP -> FROM SERVER:

SMTP -> FROM SERVER:

SMTP -> ERROR: EHLO not accepted from server:

SMTP -> FROM SERVER:

SMTP -> ERROR: HELO not accepted from server:

SMTP -> ERROR: AUTH not accepted from server: 477 you did not wait for a prompt

SMTP -> FROM SERVER:

SMTP -> ERROR: RSET failed:

mailer error: SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.

Does anyone have an idea of what the issue might be???  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Which version of phpmailer are you using ? Can you post some PHP Code ?

Comment: Have you tried to telnet to the appropriate port (25, etc) of the server to make sure you can issue these commands by hand and get the expected response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Cristian:  I'm using Version: 2.0.4.

```
    $this->load->library('PhpMailer');

    $this->phpmailer->Host = "mail.xxx.org";
    $this->phpmailer->IsSMTP();
    $this->phpmailer->SMTPAuth = true;      

    $this->phpmailer->Username = 'xxx';
    $this->phpmailer->Password = 'xxxx';

    $this->phpmailer->From= 'info@xxx.org';
    $this->phpmailer->FromName = 'xxx Info';

    $this->phpmailer->AddReplyTo('info@xxx.org', 'Info');

    $this->phpmailer->Subject = 'Php mailer test';

    $this->phpmailer->Body = 'test msg body';

    $this->phpmailer->SMTPDebug = 2;

    $this->phpmailer->AddAddress('example@xxx.com', 'BlackTie');

    if(!$this->phpmailer->Send()){
        echo 'mailer error: ' . $this->phpmailer->ErrorInfo;
    }else{
        echo 'msg sent';
    }
```

Here's the error message:

SMTP -> FROM SERVER:

SMTP -> FROM SERVER:

SMTP -> ERROR: EHLO not accepted from server:

SMTP -> FROM SERVER:

SMTP -> ERROR: HELO not accepted from server:

SMTP -> ERROR: AUTH not accepted from server: 477 you did not wait for a prompt

SMTP -> FROM SERVER:

SMTP -> ERROR: RSET failed: 
mailer error: SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.