# phpmailer error on from email, PHP email

Tags: php, phpmailer

Ok I've been knocking my head against a wall, more for the overall problem of send an email thru PHP while specifying a mail server...

The solution I've made it the furthest with is phpmailer.
If there is a lightweight VERY easy solution - please suggest it.

here's what I have (obviously the u/p are NOT the real u/p - but they are in my code - the same account I get my gmail from in outlook, settings work FINE there...

Im using it as a test - because the smtp settings the client gave me didn't work - so I though I'd try something that I KNEW - DID work...

```
<?php
require 'phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
$mail->Debugoutput = 'html';
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->Port = 465;
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = "me@myDomain.com";
$mail->Password = "myPassword";
$mail->SetFrom('me@myDomain.com', 'James Test');
$mail->AddAddress('me@yahoo.com', 'John Doe');
$mail->Subject = 'PHPMailer SMTP test';
$mail->MsgHTML( 'This is a test' );

//Send the message, check for errors
if( !$mail -> Send() ) {
echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
echo "Message sent!";
}
?>
```

The error I'm getting

```
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:
CLIENT -> SMTP: EHLO dev.nps.com
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:
SMTP -> ERROR: EHLO not accepted from server:
CLIENT -> SMTP: HELO dev.nps.com
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:
SMTP -> ERROR: HELO not accepted from server:
CLIENT -> SMTP: AUTH LOGIN
SMTP -> ERROR: AUTH not accepted from server:
SMTP -> NOTICE: EOF caught while checking if connected
The following From address failed: me@myDomain.com : Called Mail() without being connected
Mailer Error: The following From address failed: me@myDomain.com : Called Mail() without being connected
```

The dev.nps.com is simply a 'fake' domain I put in my host file, so i can distinguish my projects and not use 127.0.0.1 for everything... it's not specified in the code - so I'm not sure what's going on there, but the error seems to balk at the 'from email'... which again is weird because it shouldn't matter

Thanks for any help -

Comment: have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5757593/problem-with-smtp-emails-sent-via-phpmailer-helo-not-accepted

Comment: and also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3618712/sending-emails-through-smtp-with-phpmailer

Comment: Nicholas - thx for the links - in the first one the solution is a port number and the second articles solution is authentication....

If Im missing something about gmail auth - that is a possibility, but I can't stress enough that these very setting WORK in my mail client AND on my coldfsuion server to send mail. the ONLY difference on the u/p and server/port are the fact that Im using PHPmailer .. from the SAME box (either my laptop for dev OR my co-lo server)... so i have a hard time believing it's a gmail auth issue.

Comment: it may not be a gmail issue it may be a phpmailer issue in that it needs either 

$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
or
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';

to be set

Comment: God bless you Nicholas -  $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; - works beautifully!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!